# levelplot() not rendering png from commandline

Tags: r, graphics, lattice, levelplot

I am making use of the levelplot() function from the lattice package. My R version is 3.4.3

When I run the following code from RStudio, the png is created as expected

```
# minimal reproducible example

require(lattice)

setwd("Z:/")
png(file = "example.png", width = 1200, height = 800)
vec <- 1:10
mat <- matrix(vec, ncol = 10, nrow = 10)
levelplot(mat)
dev.off()
```

[png output when ran from RStudio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hhcjf.png)

However, when I run from command line (in Windows 10) using the following command*, the png renders as an entirely white canvas.
*note : I'm running this command from ...\R\R-3.4.3\bin , and need to run this way because this is how I trigger R scripts from a different program.

```
Rscript.exe -e "source('Z:/latticeErrorReproducibleExample.R')"
```

[png output when ran from command line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uj3h9.png)

how can I get the png to render correctly from commandline?
the script this error is derived from is correctly rendering numerous other png files generated from Base-R functions (line plots as well as 3d persp() plots), but is failing for levelplot()

Comment: This is a many times over SO duplicate as well as an item in the #7 section of the R-FAQ.

Comment: Use `print(levelplot(mat))`

Comment: thanks. I did search for this stuff, but used the wrong keywords apparently